# gnu linker script - stm32f4xx - global variables

Tags: c, gnu, stm32, stm32f4discovery, linker-scripts

i would like to make the memory map (start and end addresses of section) available in my firmware: example: i would like to know where the origin of the user_data section starts (0x8800000) and how long it is (512K). I saw it in an example once, it is possible to define global variables in the linker script where the firmware then can access it (extern unsigned long GLOBAL_VAR_USER_SECTION_BEGIN). can someone help my where and how i need to declare the global variable?

### linker script memory map

```
MEMORY
{
RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 128K
CCMRAM (rw)    : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 64K
/* BL (rx)         : ORIGIN = 0x8000000,  LENGTH = 32K */
FLASH (rx)     : ORIGIN = 0x8000000,  LENGTH = 512K
USER_DATA (rw) : ORIGIN = 0x8800000,  LENGTH = 512K /* user data section of 512K */
}
```

### linker script

```
/*
*****************************************************************************
**
**  File        : LinkerScript.ld
**
**  Abstract    : Linker script for STM32F407VGTx Device with
**                1024KByte FLASH, 128KByte RAM
**
**                Set heap size, stack size and stack location according
**                to application requirements.
**
**                Set memory bank area and size if external memory is used.
**
**  Target      : STMicroelectronics STM32
**
**
**  Distribution: The file is distributed as is, without any warranty
**                of any kind.
**
**  (c)Copyright Ac6.
**  You may use this file as-is or modify it according to the needs of your
**  project. Distribution of this file (unmodified or modified) is not
**  permitted. Ac6 permit registered System Workbench for MCU users the
**  rights to distribute the assembled, compiled & linked contents of this
**  file as part of an application binary file, provided that it is built
**  using the System Workbench for MCU toolchain.
**
*****************************************************************************
*/

/* Entry Point */
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)

/* Highest address of the user mode stack */
_estack = 0x20020000;    /* end of RAM */

/* Generate a link error if heap and stack don't fit into RAM */
_Min_Heap_Size = 0x0;    /* required amount of heap  : heap is not used */
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x400; /* required amount of stack : 1K minimal stack size */

/* Specify the memory areas                                     */
/* (xrw) : execute, read, write                                 */
/* Flash: 1M, RAM 128K, CCMRAM: 64K                             */
/* Examples: xK == x'000 * 1.024 B : 128K == 131'072 (0x20'000) */
MEMORY
{
RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 128K
CCMRAM (rw)    : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 64K
/* BL (rx)         : ORIGIN = 0x8000000,  LENGTH = 32K */
FLASH (rx)     : ORIGIN = 0x8000000,  LENGTH = 512K
USER_DATA (rw) : ORIGIN = 0x8800000,  LENGTH = 512K /* user data section of 512K */
}

/* Define output sections */
SECTIONS
{
  /* The startup code goes first into FLASH */
  .isr_vector :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Startup code */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH

  /* The program code and other data goes into FLASH */
  .text :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.text)           /* .text sections (code) */
    *(.text*)          /* .text* sections (code) */
    *(.glue_7)         /* glue arm to thumb code */
    *(.glue_7t)        /* glue thumb to arm code */
    *(.eh_frame)

    KEEP (*(.init))
    KEEP (*(.fini))

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _etext = .;        /* define a global symbols at end of code */
  } >FLASH

  /* Constant data goes into FLASH */
  .rodata :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.rodata)         /* .rodata sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    *(.rodata*)        /* .rodata* sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH

  .ARM.extab   : { *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*) } >FLASH
  .ARM : {
    __exidx_start = .;
    *(.ARM.exidx*)
    __exidx_end = .;
  } >FLASH

  .preinit_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
  .init_array :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
  .fini_array :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH

  /* used by the startup to initialize data */
  _sidata = LOADADDR(.data);

  /* Initialized data sections goes into RAM, load LMA copy after code */
  .data : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdata = .;        /* create a global symbol at data start */
    *(.data)           /* .data sections */
    *(.data*)          /* .data* sections */

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = .;        /* define a global symbol at data end */
  } >RAM AT> FLASH

  _siccmram = LOADADDR(.ccmram);

  /* CCM-RAM section 
  * 
  * IMPORTANT NOTE! 
  * If initialized variables will be placed in this section,
  * the startup code needs to be modified to copy the init-values.  
  */
  .ccmram :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sccmram = .;       /* create a global symbol at ccmram start */
    *(.ccmram)
    *(.ccmram*)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _eccmram = .;       /* create a global symbol at ccmram end */
  } >CCMRAM AT> FLASH

  /* user data section : 3 different names!                                 */
  /* this places every code with this sections attribute to this section    */ 
  /*                                                                        */
  /* __attribute__((section(".USER_Data"))) int placed_logic()              */
  /* {                                                                      */
  /*   TODO - Add your application code here                                */
  /*   return 1;                                                            */
  /* }                                                                      */
  .user_data :
  {
    *(.USER_Data*);
  } > USER_DATA

  /* Uninitialized data section */
  . = ALIGN(4);
  .bss :
  {
    /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .bss secion */
    _sbss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss start */
    __bss_start__ = _sbss;
    *(.bss)
    *(.bss*)
    *(COMMON)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ebss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss end */
    __bss_end__ = _ebss;
  } >RAM

  /* User_heap_stack section, used to check that there is enough RAM left */
  ._user_heap_stack :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    PROVIDE ( end = . );
    PROVIDE ( _end = . );
    . = . + _Min_Heap_Size;
    . = . + _Min_Stack_Size;
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >RAM

  /* Remove information from the standard libraries */
  /DISCARD/ :
  {
    libc.a ( * )
    libm.a ( * )
    libgcc.a ( * )
  }

  .ARM.attributes 0 : { *(.ARM.attributes) }
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at [this link](https://mcuoneclipse.com/2012/11/01/defining-variables-at-absolute-addresses-with-gcc/).

Comment: Hi gaurav. Did i understand this correctly, this allows me to place any variable ad a defined location? Im my case where i would like to access the memory map from the linker script, how could i write those values with the linker script into a variable?

Comment: Do you want to access a variable declared and set in linker file inside your C code?

Comment: Yes exactly ;) do you know how to do this?

Comment: `it is possible to define global variables in the linker` - no variables, symbols. It makes a huuuuge difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate your memory and linkage descriptor files from within make and then use variables on the compiler command line to define constants (i.e. `-D` option). Or you could even generate a header file full of `#define`s:

mem.tbl:

```
RAM_START = 1234
RAM_LENGTH = 5678
```

makefile:

```
include mem.tbl

define MEM_DESC =
MEMORY
{
   RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = $(RAM_START), LENGTH = $(RAM_LENGTH)
   CCMRAM (rw)    : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 64K
   /* BL (rx)         : ORIGIN = 0x8000000,  LENGTH = 32K */
   FLASH (rx)     : ORIGIN = 0x8000000,  LENGTH = 512K
   USER_DATA (rw) : ORIGIN = 0x8800000,  LENGTH = 512K /* user data section of 512K */
}
endef

define MEM_INCLUDE =
#define RAM_START $(RAM_START)
#define RAM_LENGTH $(RAM_LENGTH)
endef


all: mem.map mem.h
    @echo use the header file in your compilation
    @cat mem.h
    @echo and the memory map in your linking
    @cat mem.map

mem.h : mem.tbl
    $(file > mem.h,$(MEM_INCLUDE))

mem.map: mem.tbl
    $(file > mem.map,$(MEM_DESC))
```

Or you take this one step further and use [the GNUmake table toolkit](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt/) which provides functions for build management from within make. It was written with multi-platform and cross-development/embedded in mind and offers arithmetic, table processing and other handy things.

Answer (score -1):

Defining symbols in the linker script can be easily done, your file contains some examples. In the `.data` section, the symbols `_sdata` and `_edata` are already defined, like said in the comment (`create a global symbol at data start`).

Once created in the linker script, you can use those symbols from the C code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void display_data_start(void)
{
    extern int _sdata;

    printf("_sdata:%x\n", &_sdata);
}
```

So `&_sdata` will contain the start address of the `.data` section.

Comment: hi.
i tried as follows:
extern int _MYDATA;
int main(void)
{
  int aaa = _MYDATA;
  aaa++;
}
  /* Initialized data sections goes into RAM, load LMA copy after code */
  .data : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _MYDATA = 0x123456; /* fixme */

but this gives my hard fault.

Comment: Wrong. &_sdata or in your case &_MYDATA- there are not the variables only symbols!!